# Facebook Recommendations Bar and dynamic content?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-recommendations

OK I have a portfolio at http://www.gablabelle.com/. When you click a thumbnail a slide (of a slider) comes in with the requested photo. Great.

I have the Facebook Recommendations Bar installed as you can see in the lower right corner. I want the Like button to be linked to slide I am on at that specific moment.

A simplified version of the code:

```
slider.ev.on('SlideChange', function(event) {
// Show me the URL, works fine
    console.log(href);
// Trying to change the URL of the Facebook Recommandations Bar plugin
    $(".fb-recommendations-bar").attr("data-href", href);
// The trigger
    FB.XFBML.RecommendationsBar.markRead(href);
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="social" class="hide">
    <div class="fb-recommendations-bar" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/gablabellephoto" num_recommendations="0" data-trigger="manual" data-site="http://www.gablabelle.com/"></div>
</div>
```

The Facebook documentation says the followings:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendationsbar/

> manual - use this option to manually trigger the plugin. When you want
>   to trigger the plugin, call
>   FB.XFBML.RecommendationsBar.markRead(href); in JavaScript. The href
>   parameter is optional and will default to the current page if not set.
>   If provided, it must match the href parameter on the XFBML tag. The
>   manual trigger is useful when you have more a multi-page article. For
>   example on a three page article, you would add trigger="manual" on
>   pages one and two and never call the markRead JavaScript function on
>   those pages.

Many thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

OK using

```
$(".fb-recommendations-bar").data("href", href);
```

instead of

```
$(".fb-recommendations-bar").attr("data-href", href);
```

and

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

or

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('.fb-recommendations-bar'));
```

instead of

```
FB.XFBML.RecommendationsBar.markRead(href);
```

works!